# store fetched data into array and compare array for difference

Tags: mysql, php

I am trying to find out difference between two array but not able to solve this problem.

This is the code that i am trying

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db( 'db1' );
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
$array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $array[] = $row;
}

$result = array_diff($array,$array);
echo $result;
```

it is showing array to string conversion error. Please suggest on this problem.

Comment: HI Seventyeightist, thanks for the reply. i made the suggested changes but it is showing warning(Notice: Array to string conversion) in $result=array_diff($array,$array);

Comment: I've raised a suggestion to move this to Stack Overflow as it would fit better there; the issue is with the PHP code rather than the database.

Comment: Well, `$result = array_diff($array,$array);` is the same array anyway... The mysql query code isn't right either. If it gets punted to SO it'll be closed.

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` API.

Comment: Hi Rick James, thanks for the reply. I am using this with oracle db. this is just for the demo. There also i am facing same problem.